# "Delete files script" continue to next pc if a pc on list is turned off issue

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a script to delete all files in my Epson Scans Folder. In my pclist.txt i have each pc name listed on each line. I am trying to figure out how to adjust this script to continue to the following pc if a pc on the list is not on. The script runs perfect if all pcs are turned on. But if a pc is turned off it stops running and does not move on to the next pc in the list. Does anyone know how I can adjust for that?

Note: pclist.txt is just a list of pc names

```
@echo off
IF "%CD%\" NEQ "%~dp0" PUSHD "%~dp0"

for /F %%G in (pclist.txt) do ( 

pushd "\\%%G\C$\Epson Scans" || exit /B 1
for /D %%I in ("*") do (
    rd /S /Q "%%~I"
)
del /Q "*"
popd

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `exit /B` command, so it is no surprise that the script terminates in case `pushd` fails. The `||` constitutes a conditional command concatenation operator which lets the following command execute only in case the previous one fails (that is, it returns a non-zero exit code).

So I would remove the `|| exit /B 1` part and simply reverse the logic, so that the deletions are accomplished only in case `pushd` succeeds to connect to the drive. There is also an `&&` operator that lets the following command execute in case the preceding one succeeded, which I would use:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%~dp0pclist.txt") do ( 
    pushd "\\%%G\C$\Epson Scans" && (
        rem Perform the actual deletions in case of successful connection:
        for /D %%I in ("*") do (
            rd /S /Q "%%~I"
        )
        del /Q "*"
        popd
    ) || (
        rem Do something in case of failure, like printing an error message:
        >&2 echo Could not connect "%%G"!
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ping` command (with `-n 1` tries only 1 time)  and test using ERRORLEVEL variable

```
ping -n 1 MYSERVER > nul
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  echo "MYSERVER IS OK"
)
```

In your script:

```
@echo off
IF "%CD%\" NEQ "%~dp0" PUSHD "%~dp0"

for /F %%G in (pclist.txt) do ( 

   ping -n 1 %%G > nul
   if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (

    pushd "\\%%G\C$\Epson Scans" || exit /B 1
    for /D %%I in ("*") do (
        rd /S /Q "%%~I"
    )
    del /Q "*"
    popd

   )
)
```